# Azure : cannot use selected subscription

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

On trying t create the new Azure notification hub, the error

> Cannot use Selected Subscription

[image]

appears. Can someone please let me know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the Notification Hub provider registered in the subscription?

In the portal, go to All Services->Subscriptions->Your Subscription.  Scroll to Resource Providers and search for Microsoft.NotificationHubs.  See if it is listed as "Registered" or "NotRegistered" If not register, click Register and then try and create the Notification Hub again.

Comment: As a follow up you can also use [Azure Powershell to register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/register-azurermresourceprovider?view=azurermps-6.13.0) or [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/provider?view=azure-cli-latest#az-provider-register) to register as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to Register the Resource Provider NotificationsHubs, you can either do it from the **[portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application)** or via c# code

We could use the following function in the Azure fluent resource management to registry providers.

[image]

```
var result=resourceManagementClient.Providers.Register("provider name");
```

Comment: You answer is correct too, I just found it easier to follow DreadedForest instructions, hence marking that as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: yeah his one is the right and fastest. i just added more details